# Cant Fully Install Hawq on Ambari

Tags: ambari, hawq

Im trying to run Pivotal Hawq with Ambari. I add the Hawq repository and install the Hawq and PXF through ambari. I have 4 nodes and so the configuration would be 1 Hawq master and 3 segment. The master is started correctly, but i only can start 2 of the 3 segments, one of the segments is always giving the error represented on the image  [error_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRrBJ.png). The error its like no hawq service is not installed.
Can someons give some help?

Answer (score 0):

hawq command not found on segment. Make sure you have hawq repo on segment host (yum repolist or yum provides hawq). Do you have httpd running on hawq repo node?

Comment: Yes i have the repo, both command detect the repo and the httpd is running too

Comment: Try an `rpm -qa | grep hawq` - if nothing is returned you'll need to do a `yum install hawq` from the offending node.

Comment: The rpm returned some content, even so, i tried to run yum install hawq and it says its already installed.

Comment: I've been in similar situation. I had an old version of hawq in segments.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to start the hawq segment. I had to remove all haqwq components and then add the segment manually on ambari, then it worked